# How to retrieve a mask for a partially filled 3D Truncated SDF based on its ground truth?

Tags: 3d, signed-distance-field, masking

I am trying to create a mask which is required for a 3D inpainting task. My data contains 3D truncated SDF grid of size `64*64*64` with a truncated value of `3`. I tried a couple of methods including the following, but none is able to produce satisfactory results. What am I missing here?

```
def generate_mask(partial_object, ground_truth, device):

    threshold = 3.0
    truncation = 3.0
    target_mask = torch.zeros(ground_truth.shape).bool()
    target_mask[np.where((ground_truth.cpu().detach().numpy() < threshold) & (ground_truth.cpu().detach().numpy() > -threshold))] = True   # True, if inside the surface
    
    input_mask = torch.zeros(partial_object.shape).bool()
    input_mask[np.where((partial_object.cpu().detach().numpy() < threshold) & (partial_object.cpu().detach().numpy() > -threshold))] = True
    
    mask = target_mask ^ input_mask
    mask = mask.to(device)
    
    return mask
```

The code mostly results an object almost similar to the ground truth.